# How to add checkboxes in Android App toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

I need to add a `Checkbox` in `Android App bar`. my `Menu_main` as follow:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Right now it's showing `Title` and `search` icon. How can I add  a `Checkbox` in `Bar` right next to `Search` icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to add `CheckBox` in menu .
1. User direct class (Action View) e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".tariff.ui.SearchOffersActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_checkbox"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
        android:title="@string/filter"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

2- You can use custom layout [LINK](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-a-custom-layout-to-badge-androids-action-bar-menu-items/)

Comment: Oh! Thanks it works perfectly :)
How can I change color of checkboxes? Right now it's black.

Comment: @SnowClue if it is working, then accept my answer :)
For color, you may set theme in style.

Comment: How can I set a theme for a specific `<item>` ?

Comment: Set theme in Style.xml for Chack Boxes what you want. OR you can also set custom layout as in answer

Comment: Sorry spell mistake "CheckBox"

Comment: Actually I am not getting where to set the theme. Can you please help me in that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93072/discussion-between-mohammad-imran-and-snowclue).