# Android ImageButton on Toolbar doesn't have pressed/selected state

Tags: android

I put a view on my toolbar and I have an `ImageButton`with custom background which does not change state when I press on it. My toolbar's code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

where `custom_toolbar`is:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

  <..views..>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_id"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/my_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/my_bg" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and `my_bg` is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_pressed" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_simples" android:state_selected="false" />
```

Comment: Try by replacing your imageButton with checkbox where you can set custom icon (set the selector to checkbox). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280354/how-to-add-checkboxes-in-android-app-toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:background="@drawable/my_bg"` to `android:src="@drawable/my_bg"`

Answer (score 0):

You Should Try This , I think it Works
**Best Of Luck**

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_pressed" android:state_selected="true" />
    </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"  />
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_simples" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

Hope this will work~